# Transaction across 2 databases, hibernate + JPA in a standalone java application

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jta

We have a java application which is standalone.Currently we connect to only one database,it works fine.We have  a new requirement where we have to connect to a second database and one of the transactions has to actually insert data into both the databases.
Is there a way we can do this using hibernate. I tried to use the HibernateEntityManager and configured it to point to the 2 databases, but the commit is the problem.

Is there a way to do this without JTA ? Or if  JTA is the only option ... is going for an App server better or should we just go for a standalone JTA implementation.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

This is called a two-phase commit, where commits need to happen across multiple systems (another example would be dequeueing a JMS message along with a DB transaction).

As suspected, JTA is the way to go here, and you'll need an XA-compliant JDBC driver to be able to span the transaction across connections.

You don't necessarily need an app server, but many of them give you built-in capabilities that you would otherwise need to implement yourself (here's an example: http://blog.springsource.com/2011/08/15/configuring-spring-and-jta-without-full-java-ee/).  if you use JBoss, for instance, it comes with a full XA-compliant tx coordinator built-in.